# Delphi SQLConnection via ODBC on Linux cannot connect to SQL

Tags: linux, sql-server-2008, delphi, odbc

I have successfully installed two Linux virtual machines.
One is with ZorinOS 32 bit, unixodbc and FreeTDS driver for MS SQL.
Second is Fedora 23 64 bit, unixodbc and Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server on Linux.
I setup the ODBC and I can connect to SQL Server, on the first machine via isql utility.
On the second machine, I can connect via isql and sqlcmd utilities.

Problem is with Delphi and TSQLConnection.
I have blank form, and a TSQLConnection and a button.

TSQLConnection:

```
object SQLConnection1: TSQLConnection
ConnectionName = 'OdbcConnection'
DriverName = 'Odbc'
LoginPrompt = False
Params.Strings = (
  'DriverName=Odbc'
  'DataBase=XXXX'
  'User_Name=xxx'
  'Password=xxx'
  'IsolationLevel=ReadCommitted'
  'RowSetSize=20'
  'ConnectionString=')
Left = 64
Top = 28
```

end
button event:

```
SQLConnection1.Connected := true;
```

on Windows it connects,
on both Linux machines I get:
DBX Error: Error Code: -1.

Whats wrong???

p.s. SQL is 2008 and Delphi is XE4

Comment: Shouldn't be your drivername=FreeTDS instead of Odbc on the linux systems?

Comment: well no, I get this error in that case: Unknown driver: FreeTDS, even in /etc/odbcinst.ini states [FreeTDS]. Similiar for MS driver: Unknown driver: ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Well to answer to myself...
I was able to connect with FireDAC components in XE6

```
object FDConnection1: TFDConnection
Params.Strings = (
  'Database=XXXXX'
  'User_Name=xxx'
  'Password=xxx'
  'DataSource=xxxxx'
  'DriverID=ODBC')
Connected = True
LoginPrompt = False
Left = 200
Top = 32
end

object FDPhysODBCDriverLink1: TFDPhysODBCDriverLink
ODBCDriver = 'SQL Server'
Left = 288
Top = 8
end
```

With dbExpress in XE6 (and XE4), I had no luck.